# WPF App - Japanese character not rendered

Tags: .net, wpf, windows

I deployed a WPF application to a customer in Japan.

The Japanese translation works correctly on my PC with Windows 10 but not in his PC with Windows 7 Embedded Standard:

[image]

Do I have to install a new font? If yes which one?

Thanks,

Comment: You can always inspect your UI at runtime with Snoop. Look at the text box, look at the FontFamily and related properties. What fonts are listed? What fonts are installed on the system?

Comment: Hi I downloaded Snoop but it does not list my application in the combobox. Do I have to rebuild it from source?

Anyway the Embedded version of windows does not have the Japanese language. Do you know where should I look for the language pack? I cannot find it in windows update

Comment: You have to click the refresh button or hit f5 for that dropdown to be populated. Also, there's a crosshair button to the right of the binocular button you can use to select the window. Click and drag it on top of the WPF window you want to examine. If those don't work, you aren't developing a WPF application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and install the Japanese language pack and fonts from the *Windows Embedded Standard 7 DVD* furnished with the industrial PC.

Fonts:

- msgothic.ttc
- meiryo.ttc
- meiryob.ttc
- msmincho.ttc

That can be found in:

- WinEmb-Font-Japanese-Required.cab
- WinEmb-Font-Japanese-Supplement.cab

Language Pack:

- x86~microsoft-windows-embedded-languagepack-package~ja-jp~~~6.1.7601.17514~1.0\lp.cab